# fast bit-matrix (64x64) transpose algorithm using SIMD (ARM)

Tags: assembly, arm, transpose, simd, neon

I am trying to understand, if there is a fast way to do a matrix transpose (64x64 bits) using ARM SIMD instructions.

I tried to explore the VTRN instruction of ARM SIMD but am not sure of its effective application in this scenario.

The input matrix is represented as uint64 mat[64], and the output is supposed to be a bitwise transpose.

For example if the input is:

```
0000....
1111....
0000....
1111....
```

The expected output:

```
0101....
0101....
0101....
0101....
```

Comment: That's a tough nut to crack. One thing I can tell you in advance is that you'll need to write separate versions for each `aarch32` and `aarch64` ISA due to the different register capacity.

Comment: You originally tagged this [avx].  Are you also interested in an AVX version for x86-64?  IIRC, `vpmovmskb` is quite useful for extracting 1 bit per byte after some byte shuffling.  (Probably better than `vmovmskpd` to extract 1 bit per uint64 to get nibble chunks.)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE - thanks for mentioning the complexity, for now aarch64 should be fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes i originally tagged AVX to get feedback from the AVX world, to understand if anything can be adopted for ARM from there and understanding the high-level approach.

Comment: Even AVX512 lacks useful basic instructions such as `vsli` and `vsri`. AVX in general is more or less hit-or-miss compared to neon. - if AVX has suitable instructions for specific problems, it's godsent, if not, neon is much more versatile, and thus efficient.

Comment: @sourabhjaiswal Do not apply incorrect tags to your question.  Not even to attract an audience.  That's not a nice thing to do.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE That instruction is called `palignr` on SSE and AVX if I recall correctly.

Comment: @fuz AVX doesn't have `vsli` or `vsri`. `alignr` is equivalent to `vext`

Answer (score 6):

The basic recursive scheme for a matrix transposition is to represent the matrix as a block matrix

```
AB
CD
```

which you transpose by first transposing each of A, B, C, and D and then swapping B and C.  In practice this means applying a sequence of increasingly coarse swizzle steps, first using bitwise operations and later using permutation operations.

This can for example be implemented [as follows](https://github.com/clausecker/xpose64x64/blob/master/xpose.S):

```
    # transpose a 64x64 bit matrix held in x0
    GLOBL(xpose_asm)
FUNC(xpose_asm)
    # plan of attack: use registers v16--v32 to hold
    # half the array, v0--v7 for scratch.  First transpose
    # the two array halves individually, then swap the
    # second and third quarters.
    mov x4, lr

    mov x2, x0
    bl  NAME(xpose_half)
    mov x3, x0
    bl  NAME(xpose_half)

    # final step: transpose 64x64 bit matrices
    # we have to do this one in two parts as to not run
    # out of registers
    mov x5, x2
    mov x6, x3
    bl  NAME(xpose_final)
    bl  NAME(xpose_final)

    ret x4
ENDFUNC(xpose_asm)

    # Transpose half a 32x64 bit matrix held in x0.
    # On return, advance x0 by 32*8 = 256 byte.
FUNC(xpose_half)
    # v16 holds rows 0 and 4, v17 holds 1 and 5, and so on
    mov x1, x0
    ld4 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x0], #64
    ld4 {v20.2d, v21.2d, v22.2d, v23.2d}, [x0], #64
    ld4 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x0], #64
    ld4 {v28.2d, v29.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d}, [x0], #64

    # macro for a transposition step.  Trashes v6 and v7
.macro  xpstep lo, hi, mask, shift
    ushr v6.2d, \lo\().2d, #\shift
    shl v7.2d, \hi\().2d, #\shift
    bif \lo\().16b, v7.16b, \mask\().16b
    bit \hi\().16b, v6.16b, \mask\().16b
.endm

    # 1st step: transpose 2x2 bit matrices
    movi    v0.16b, #0x55
    xpstep  v16, v17, v0, 1
    xpstep  v18, v19, v0, 1
    xpstep  v20, v21, v0, 1
    xpstep  v22, v23, v0, 1
    xpstep  v24, v25, v0, 1
    xpstep  v26, v27, v0, 1
    xpstep  v28, v29, v0, 1
    xpstep  v30, v31, v0, 1

    # 2nd step: transpose 4x4 bit matrices
    movi    v0.16b, #0x33
    xpstep  v16, v18, v0, 2
    xpstep  v17, v19, v0, 2
    xpstep  v20, v22, v0, 2
    xpstep  v21, v23, v0, 2
    xpstep  v24, v26, v0, 2
    xpstep  v25, v27, v0, 2
    xpstep  v28, v30, v0, 2
    xpstep  v29, v31, v0, 2

    # immediate step: zip vectors to change
    # colocation.  As a side effect, every other
    # vector is temporarily relocated to the v0..v7
    # register range
    zip1    v0.2d,  v16.2d, v17.2d
    zip2    v17.2d, v16.2d, v17.2d
    zip1    v1.2d,  v18.2d, v19.2d
    zip2    v19.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d
    zip1    v2.2d,  v20.2d, v21.2d
    zip2    v21.2d, v20.2d, v21.2d
    zip1    v3.2d,  v22.2d, v23.2d
    zip2    v23.2d, v22.2d, v23.2d
    zip1    v4.2d,  v24.2d, v25.2d
    zip2    v25.2d, v24.2d, v25.2d
    zip1    v5.2d,  v26.2d, v27.2d
    zip2    v27.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d
    zip1    v6.2d,  v28.2d, v29.2d
    zip2    v29.2d, v28.2d, v29.2d
    zip1    v7.2d,  v30.2d, v31.2d
    zip2    v31.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d

    # macro for the 3rd transposition step
    # swap low 4 bit of each hi member with
    # high 4 bit of each orig member.  The orig
    # members are copied to lo in the process.
.macro  xpstep3 lo, hi, orig
    mov \lo\().16b, \orig\().16b
    sli \lo\().16b, \hi\().16b, #4
    sri \hi\().16b, \orig\().16b, #4
.endm

    # 3rd step: transpose 8x8 bit matrices
    # special code is needed here since we need to
    # swap row n row line n+4, but these rows are
    # always colocated in the same register
    xpstep3 v16, v17, v0
    xpstep3 v18, v19, v1
    xpstep3 v20, v21, v2
    xpstep3 v22, v23, v3
    xpstep3 v24, v25, v4
    xpstep3 v26, v27, v5
    xpstep3 v28, v29, v6
    xpstep3 v30, v31, v7

    # registers now hold
    # v16: { 0,  1}  v17: { 4,  5}  v18: { 2,  3}  v19: { 6,  7}
    # v20: { 8,  9}  v21: {12, 13}  v22: {10, 11}  v23: {14, 15}
    # v24: {16, 17}  v25: {20, 21}  v26: {18, 19}  v27: {22, 23}
    # v28: {24, 25}  v29: {28, 29}  v30: {26, 27}  v31: {30, 31}

    # 4th step: transpose 16x16 bit matrices
    # this step again moves half the registers to v0--v7
    trn1    v0.16b,  v16.16b, v20.16b
    trn2    v20.16b, v16.16b, v20.16b
    trn1    v1.16b,  v17.16b, v21.16b
    trn2    v21.16b, v17.16b, v21.16b
    trn1    v2.16b,  v18.16b, v22.16b
    trn2    v22.16b, v18.16b, v22.16b
    trn1    v3.16b,  v19.16b, v23.16b
    trn2    v23.16b, v19.16b, v23.16b
    trn1    v4.16b,  v24.16b, v28.16b
    trn2    v28.16b, v24.16b, v28.16b
    trn1    v5.16b,  v25.16b, v29.16b
    trn2    v29.16b, v25.16b, v29.16b
    trn1    v6.16b,  v26.16b, v30.16b
    trn2    v30.16b, v26.16b, v30.16b
    trn1    v7.16b,  v27.16b, v31.16b
    trn2    v31.16b, v27.16b, v31.16b

    # 5th step: transpose 32x32 bit matrices
    # while we are at it, shuffle the order of
    # entries such that they are in order
    trn1    v16.8h, v0.8h, v4.8h
    trn2    v24.8h, v0.8h, v4.8h
    trn1    v18.8h, v1.8h, v5.8h
    trn2    v26.8h, v1.8h, v5.8h
    trn1    v17.8h, v2.8h, v6.8h
    trn2    v25.8h, v2.8h, v6.8h
    trn1    v19.8h, v3.8h, v7.8h
    trn2    v27.8h, v3.8h, v7.8h

    trn1    v0.8h, v20.8h, v28.8h
    trn2    v4.8h, v20.8h, v28.8h
    trn1    v2.8h, v21.8h, v29.8h
    trn2    v6.8h, v21.8h, v29.8h
    trn1    v1.8h, v22.8h, v30.8h
    trn2    v5.8h, v22.8h, v30.8h
    trn1    v3.8h, v23.8h, v31.8h
    trn2    v7.8h, v23.8h, v31.8h

    # now deposit the partially transposed matrix
    st1 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x1], #64
    st1 {v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d, v3.2d}, [x1], #64
    st1 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x1], #64
    st1 {v4.2d, v5.2d, v6.2d, v7.2d}, [x1], #64

    ret
ENDFUNC(xpose_half)

FUNC(xpose_final)
    ld1 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x2], #64
    ld1 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x3], #64
    ld1 {v20.2d, v21.2d, v22.2d, v23.2d}, [x2], #64
    ld1 {v28.2d, v29.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d}, [x3], #64

    trn1    v0.4s, v16.4s, v24.4s
    trn2    v4.4s, v16.4s, v24.4s
    trn1    v1.4s, v17.4s, v25.4s
    trn2    v5.4s, v17.4s, v25.4s
    trn1    v2.4s, v18.4s, v26.4s
    trn2    v6.4s, v18.4s, v26.4s
    trn1    v3.4s, v19.4s, v27.4s
    trn2    v7.4s, v19.4s, v27.4s

    trn1    v16.4s, v20.4s, v28.4s
    trn2    v24.4s, v20.4s, v28.4s
    trn1    v17.4s, v21.4s, v29.4s
    trn2    v25.4s, v21.4s, v29.4s
    trn1    v18.4s, v22.4s, v30.4s
    trn2    v26.4s, v22.4s, v30.4s
    trn1    v19.4s, v23.4s, v31.4s
    trn2    v27.4s, v23.4s, v31.4s

    st1 {v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d, v3.2d}, [x5], #64
    st1 {v4.2d, v5.2d, v6.2d, v7.2d}, [x6], #64
    st1 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x5], #64
    st1 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x6], #64

    ret
ENDFUNC(xpose_final)
```

We can see that the performance compares well to [Lee's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71556367/417501), being about three times faster.

```
# Apple M1
name  time/op
Ref      764ns ± 0%
Lee      102ns ± 0%
Fuz     34.7ns ± 0%

name  speed
Ref    670MB/s ± 0%
Lee   5.01GB/s ± 0%
Fuz   14.7GB/s ± 0%


# Kunpeng 920
name  time/op
Ref     3.73µs ± 0%
Lee      391ns ± 1%
Fuz     96.0ns ± 0%

name  speed
Ref    137MB/s ± 0%
Lee   1.31GB/s ± 1%
Fuz   5.33GB/s ± 0%


# ARM Cortex A72
name  time/op
Ref     8.13µs ± 0%
Lee      892ns ± 0%
Fuz      296ns ± 0%

name  speed
Ref   63.0MB/s ± 0%
Lee    574MB/s ± 0%
Fuz   1.73GB/s ± 0%


# Cavium ThunderX
name  time/op
Ref     19.7µs ± 0%
Lee     1.15µs ± 0%
Fuz      690ns ± 0%

name  speed
Ref   25.9MB/s ± 0%
Lee    444MB/s ± 0%
Fuz    742MB/s ± 0%
```

Further improvements are likely possible.  For example, a suitable permutation mask could be used with the `tbl` set of instructions to perform multiple transposition steps (especially steps 3 to 5) at once.

Note that the algorithm has to load and write out the array just twice.  Once to transpose every 32x32 sub array (the two calls to `xpose_half`) and once more to swap the top right with the bottom left 32x32 sub array.  In both cases, maximum width 64 byte loads and stores were used, reducing the amount of memory operations to a minimum.

Comment: If you were transposing into a new destination, rather than in-place, you could avoid the extra loads/stores at the end.  (But then you'd be touching more total memory.  But if you want a separate copy anyway, that's a win.)

Comment: @PeterCordes How could I avoid them?  There's a transposition inbetween.  Look carefully: in `xpose_final` I'm loading and storing in interleaved order to transpose the 32x32 subarrays.  I do not have enough registers to hold all matrix elements at once, so a store and reload is required at some point (as Jake Lee already remarked).

Comment: I didn't look at the code in detail; I thought when you said "once more to swap the top right with the bottom left 32x32 sub array" you were talking about just swapping two chunks of memory.  If you were writing to a separate destination, you could store to the right place without overwriting anything you hadn't read yet.  Unless there's some shuffling between registers that's still needed as part of that 2nd load / store.  Which does seem to be the case in `xpose_final`, so I got the wrong impression from the text.

Comment: `tbl` doesn't pipeline on Cortex-A57, and has ultra long latency on Cortex-A72, and thus, not a good idea.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: If you think your own strategy could still be faster with some micro-optimizations, say that.  And do your own benchmark to prove it if necessary. Posting a sub-optimal SO answer isn't a cause for shame or ridicule, only a minor amount of embarrassment sometimes.  We're all just trying to share tricks we know and/or come up with new tricks for novel questions.  Sometimes the first idea someone has isn't great.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: In the full version of this transpose, yes, of course larger chunks will need different shuffles, not just bits within 32-bit elements.  Fuz's benchmarks clearly show it's fast on the CPUs he tested; if the `tbl` at the end is a showstopper on some other microarchitectures, that's a useful point, but hardly "rudeness" or a betrayal on his part.  Presumably an oversight or something costly that's still worth it overall.  If you have any suggestions on how to implement this strategy in a way that will run even better on CPUs like A-57 or A-72, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Looks like the asm answer you just posted takes advantage of strided loads around the same shift / `bit`/`bif` building block as Fuz's initial answer.  Unlike your initial answer.  So it looks like Fuz's initial comment on your answer was right, that building up 8x8 transposes from 2x2 and 4x4 transposes (in either order) was a good strategy.  It's great that you had the time and applied your skills to making a better optimized version of the outer part.  I don't have ARM hardware to test it on myself, but hopefully fuz will test on the same CPUs as before.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Also, your asm answer loads/stores/reloads, just like you were saying was terrible [in comments under your initial intrinsics answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552776/fast-bit-matrix-64x64-transpose-algorithm-using-simd-arm/71555778#comment126475384_71556367).  I don't think Fuz was solely responsible for "starting a war", especially when his initial comments turn out to have been accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I did some investigation and reading of the other answers and implemented a few different methods (in Rust and assembly), and benchmarked them on my Apple M2 Max.

tl;dr Using the NEON instructions gives you a 2× advantage over the non-NEON versions.

Results:

```
recursive:                 163 ns/iter (+/- 10)
Hacker's Delight loop:     157 ns/iter (+/- 21)
Hacker's Delight unrolled:  60 ns/iter (+/- 4)
Lees's answer:              37 ns/iter (+/- 3)
fuz's answer:               31 ns/iter (+/- 1)
```

- The "recursive" algorithm is a basic recursive algorithm, slightly optimized using NEON `ld4` instructions, etc., but involves much more memory movement.
- The "Hacker's Delight loop" version is a pretty straightforward implementation of Hacker's Delight, Figure 7-3 (at least in the 1st edition), but modified to bit-reverse the 64-bit words to match the other answers. It looks something like:

  ```
   let mut j = 32;
   let mut m = 0xffffffffu64;
   while j != 0 {
       let mut k = 0;
       while k < 64 {
           unsafe {
               let a = *x.get_unchecked(k + j);
               let b = *x.get_unchecked(k);
               let t = (a ^ (b >> j)) & m;
               *x.get_unchecked_mut(k + j) = a ^ t;
               *x.get_unchecked_mut(k) = b ^ (t << j);
           }

           k = (k + j + 1) & !j;
       }
       j >>= 1;
       m ^= m << j;
   }
  ```

  Rust/LLVM will auto-vectorize this a little, but not a lot (as of Rust 1.76.0).
- The "Hacker's Delight unrolled" version is the same, but with the loops manually unrolled. I did not observe any auto-vectorization.
- The "Lee's answer" version is adapted from his second answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71653601/10524 -- however, I could not get the code to output correct answers, which could be my fault in transcribing it, or in the original assembly, but I'm not going to spend any more time at the moment fixing it.
- The "fuz's answer" version is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71555778/10524 -- this code does work.

There's probably a little more room for improvement in the Hacker's Delight unrolled version by switching to assembly/intrinsics for more efficient memory management, and possibly doing more efficient swaps using rotate instructions (as the book even talks about).

Lee's code outputs the transposed bits to a separate area of memory, which is one of the reasons it is slightly slower. If we don't do the copy-back, it is within the margin of error of fuz's answer. There's probably some room for improvement if we do the transform in-place.

fuz's answer seems to be the winner at the moment.

I've implemented these all in Rust (with inline assembly, where applicable) here: https://github.com/swenson/binary_matrix/tree/simd-transpose/src

Answer (score 0):

```
    .arch armv8-a
    .global transposeBitwise64x64_noob
    .text

.balign 64
.func
// void transposeBitwise64x64_noob(uint64_t *pDst, uint64_t *pSrc);
pDst    .req    x0
pSrc0   .req    x1
pSrc1   .req    x2
pDst1   .req    x3
stride  .req    x4
count   .req    w5

pDst0   .req    pDst

// no "battle plan" here. not needed for such a self-explanatory cakewalk
transposeBitwise64x64_noob:
    add     pSrc1, pSrc0, #64
    movi    v6.16b, #0xcc
    mov     stride, #128
    movi    v7.16b, #0xaa
    sub     pDst, pDst, #32
    mov     count, #2

.balign 16
1:
    ld4     {v16.16b, v17.16b, v18.16b, v19.16b}, [pSrc0], stride
    ld4     {v20.16b, v21.16b, v22.16b, v23.16b}, [pSrc1], stride
    ld4     {v24.16b, v25.16b, v26.16b, v27.16b}, [pSrc0], stride
    ld4     {v28.16b, v29.16b, v30.16b, v31.16b}, [pSrc1], stride

    stp     q16, q20, [pDst, #32]!
    subs    count, count, #1
    stp     q17, q21, [pDst, #1*64]
    stp     q18, q22, [pDst, #2*64]
    stp     q19, q23, [pDst, #3*64]
    stp     q24, q28, [pDst, #4*64]
    stp     q25, q29, [pDst, #5*64]
    stp     q26, q30, [pDst, #6*64]
    stp     q27, q31, [pDst, #7*64]
    b.ne    1b
    // 8x64 matrix transpose virtually finished. What a moron needs zip1/zip2/trn for that?
    nop

    sub     pSrc0, pDst, #32
    add     pSrc1, pDst, #256-32
    mov     count, #4
    sub     pDst0, pDst, #32
    add     pDst1, pSrc0, #256

1:
    // 8x64 matrix transpose finished on-the-fly while reloading. Again, who the hell needs permutation instructions when we have ld2/ld3/ld4?
    ld2     {v24.16b, v25.16b}, [pSrc0], #32
    ld2     {v26.16b, v27.16b}, [pSrc1], #32
    ld2     {v28.16b, v29.16b}, [pSrc0], #32
    ld2     {v30.16b, v31.16b}, [pSrc1], #32
    subs    count, count, #1

    // nosy noob shut up remark: the trns below aren't part of the matrix transpose
    trn1    v16.2d, v24.2d, v25.2d  // row0
    trn2    v17.2d, v24.2d, v25.2d  // row1
    trn1    v18.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d  // row2
    trn2    v19.2d, v26.2d, v28.2d  // row3
    trn1    v20.2d, v28.2d, v29.2d  // row4
    trn2    v21.2d, v28.2d, v29.2d  // row5
    trn1    v22.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d  // row6
    trn2    v23.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d  // row7

    mov     v24.16b, v16.16b
    mov     v25.16b, v17.16b
    mov     v26.16b, v18.16b
    mov     v27.16b, v19.16b

    sli     v16.16b, v20.16b, #4
    sli     v17.16b, v21.16b, #4
    sli     v18.16b, v22.16b, #4
    sli     v19.16b, v23.16b, #4
    sri     v20.16b, v24.16b, #4
    sri     v21.16b, v25.16b, #4
    sri     v22.16b, v26.16b, #4
    sri     v23.16b, v27.16b, #4

    shl     v24.16b, v18.16b, #2
    shl     v25.16b, v19.16b, #2
    ushr    v26.16b, v16.16b, #2
    ushr    v27.16b, v17.16b, #2
    shl     v28.16b, v22.16b, #2
    shl     v29.16b, v23.16b, #2
    ushr    v30.16b, v20.16b, #2
    ushr    v31.16b, v21.16b, #2

    bit     v16.16b, v24.16b, v6.16b
    bit     v17.16b, v25.16b, v6.16b
    bif     v18.16b, v26.16b, v6.16b
    bif     v19.16b, v27.16b, v6.16b
    bit     v20.16b, v28.16b, v6.16b
    bit     v21.16b, v29.16b, v6.16b
    bif     v22.16b, v30.16b, v6.16b
    bif     v23.16b, v31.16b, v6.16b

    shl     v24.16b, v17.16b, #1
    ushr    v25.16b, v16.16b, #1
    shl     v26.16b, v19.16b, #1
    ushr    v27.16b, v18.16b, #1
    shl     v28.16b, v21.16b, #1
    ushr    v29.16b, v20.16b, #1
    shl     v30.16b, v23.16b, #1
    ushr    v31.16b, v22.16b, #1

    bit     v16.16b, v24.16b, v7.16b
    bif     v17.16b, v25.16b, v7.16b
    bit     v18.16b, v26.16b, v7.16b
    bif     v19.16b, v27.16b, v7.16b
    bit     v20.16b, v28.16b, v7.16b
    bif     v21.16b, v29.16b, v7.16b
    bit     v22.16b, v30.16b, v7.16b
    bif     v23.16b, v31.16b, v7.16b

    st4     {v16.d, v17.d, v18.d, v19.d}[0], [pDst0], #32
    st4     {v16.d, v17.d, v18.d, v19.d}[1], [pDst1], #32
    st4     {v20.d, v21.d, v22.d, v23.d}[0], [pDst0], #32
    st4     {v20.d, v21.d, v22.d, v23.d}[1], [pDst1], #32
    b.ne    1b

// Everyone has a plan until they get punched in the mouth - Mike Tyson

.balign 16
    ret
.endfunc
.end
```

It's probably the perfect noob's code: perfectly minimized at zero latency.
I was expecting fuz to deliver something similar, but......

Still, it's a noob version after all, and I would give it a C grade (befriedigend).

Why it doesn't deserve an A grade will be made clear upon next update: bandwidth constraint and power consumption which is the **REAL** concern on modern multicore processors.

---

[Fuz's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71555778/417501) (F grade, mangelhaft):

```
    # transpose a 64x64 bit matrix held in x0
    GLOBL(xpose_asm)
FUNC(xpose_asm)
    # plan of attack: use registers v16--v32 to hold
    # half the array, v0--v7 for scratch.  First transpose
    # the two array halves individually, then swap the
    # second and third quarters.
    mov x4, lr

    mov x2, x0
    bl  NAME(xpose_half)
    mov x3, x0
    bl  NAME(xpose_half)

    # final step: transpose 64x64 bit matrices
    # we have to do this one in two parts as to not run
    # out of registers
    mov x5, x2
    mov x6, x3
    bl  NAME(xpose_final)
    bl  NAME(xpose_final)

    ret x4
ENDFUNC(xpose_asm)

    # Transpose half a 32x64 bit matrix held in x0.
    # On return, advance x0 by 32*8 = 256 byte.
FUNC(xpose_half)
    # v16 holds rows 0 and 4, v17 holds 1 and 5, and so on
    mov x1, x0
    ld4 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x0], #64
    ld4 {v20.2d, v21.2d, v22.2d, v23.2d}, [x0], #64
    ld4 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x0], #64
    ld4 {v28.2d, v29.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d}, [x0], #64

    # macro for a transposition step.  Trashes v6 and v7
.macro  xpstep lo, hi, mask, shift
    ushr v6.2d, \lo\().2d, #\shift
    shl v7.2d, \hi\().2d, #\shift
    bif \lo\().16b, v7.16b, \mask\().16b
    bit \hi\().16b, v6.16b, \mask\().16b
.endm

    # 1st step: transpose 2x2 bit matrices
    movi    v0.16b, #0x55
    xpstep  v16, v17, v0, 1
    xpstep  v18, v19, v0, 1
    xpstep  v20, v21, v0, 1
    xpstep  v22, v23, v0, 1
    xpstep  v24, v25, v0, 1
    xpstep  v26, v27, v0, 1
    xpstep  v28, v29, v0, 1
    xpstep  v30, v31, v0, 1

    # 2nd step: transpose 4x4 bit matrices
    movi    v0.16b, #0x33
    xpstep  v16, v18, v0, 2
    xpstep  v17, v19, v0, 2
    xpstep  v20, v22, v0, 2
    xpstep  v21, v23, v0, 2
    xpstep  v24, v26, v0, 2
    xpstep  v25, v27, v0, 2
    xpstep  v28, v30, v0, 2
    xpstep  v29, v31, v0, 2

    # immediate step: zip vectors to change
    # colocation.  As a side effect, every other
    # vector is temporarily relocated to the v0..v7
    # register range
    zip1    v0.2d,  v16.2d, v17.2d
    zip2    v17.2d, v16.2d, v17.2d
    zip1    v1.2d,  v18.2d, v19.2d
    zip2    v19.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d
    zip1    v2.2d,  v20.2d, v21.2d
    zip2    v21.2d, v20.2d, v21.2d
    zip1    v3.2d,  v22.2d, v23.2d
    zip2    v23.2d, v22.2d, v23.2d
    zip1    v4.2d,  v24.2d, v25.2d
    zip2    v25.2d, v24.2d, v25.2d
    zip1    v5.2d,  v26.2d, v27.2d
    zip2    v27.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d
    zip1    v6.2d,  v28.2d, v29.2d
    zip2    v29.2d, v28.2d, v29.2d
    zip1    v7.2d,  v30.2d, v31.2d
    zip2    v31.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d

    # macro for the 3rd transposition step
    # swap low 4 bit of each hi member with
    # high 4 bit of each orig member.  The orig
    # members are copied to lo in the process.
.macro  xpstep3 lo, hi, orig
    mov \lo\().16b, \orig\().16b
    sli \lo\().16b, \hi\().16b, #4
    sri \hi\().16b, \orig\().16b, #4
.endm

    # 3rd step: transpose 8x8 bit matrices
    # special code is needed here since we need to
    # swap row n row line n+4, but these rows are
    # always colocated in the same register
    xpstep3 v16, v17, v0
    xpstep3 v18, v19, v1
    xpstep3 v20, v21, v2
    xpstep3 v22, v23, v3
    xpstep3 v24, v25, v4
    xpstep3 v26, v27, v5
    xpstep3 v28, v29, v6
    xpstep3 v30, v31, v7

    # registers now hold
    # v16: { 0,  1}  v17: { 4,  5}  v18: { 2,  3}  v19: { 6,  7}
    # v20: { 8,  9}  v21: {12, 13}  v22: {10, 11}  v23: {14, 15}
    # v24: {16, 17}  v25: {20, 21}  v26: {18, 19}  v27: {22, 23}
    # v28: {24, 25}  v29: {28, 29}  v30: {26, 27}  v31: {30, 31}

    # 4th step: transpose 16x16 bit matrices
    # this step again moves half the registers to v0--v7
    trn1    v0.16b,  v16.16b, v20.16b
    trn2    v20.16b, v16.16b, v20.16b
    trn1    v1.16b,  v17.16b, v21.16b
    trn2    v21.16b, v17.16b, v21.16b
    trn1    v2.16b,  v18.16b, v22.16b
    trn2    v22.16b, v18.16b, v22.16b
    trn1    v3.16b,  v19.16b, v23.16b
    trn2    v23.16b, v19.16b, v23.16b
    trn1    v4.16b,  v24.16b, v28.16b
    trn2    v28.16b, v24.16b, v28.16b
    trn1    v5.16b,  v25.16b, v29.16b
    trn2    v29.16b, v25.16b, v29.16b
    trn1    v6.16b,  v26.16b, v30.16b
    trn2    v30.16b, v26.16b, v30.16b
    trn1    v7.16b,  v27.16b, v31.16b
    trn2    v31.16b, v27.16b, v31.16b

    # 5th step: transpose 32x32 bit matrices
    # while we are at it, shuffle the order of
    # entries such that they are in order
    trn1    v16.8h, v0.8h, v4.8h
    trn2    v24.8h, v0.8h, v4.8h
    trn1    v18.8h, v1.8h, v5.8h
    trn2    v26.8h, v1.8h, v5.8h
    trn1    v17.8h, v2.8h, v6.8h
    trn2    v25.8h, v2.8h, v6.8h
    trn1    v19.8h, v3.8h, v7.8h
    trn2    v27.8h, v3.8h, v7.8h

    trn1    v0.8h, v20.8h, v28.8h
    trn2    v4.8h, v20.8h, v28.8h
    trn1    v2.8h, v21.8h, v29.8h
    trn2    v6.8h, v21.8h, v29.8h
    trn1    v1.8h, v22.8h, v30.8h
    trn2    v5.8h, v22.8h, v30.8h
    trn1    v3.8h, v23.8h, v31.8h
    trn2    v7.8h, v23.8h, v31.8h

    # now deposit the partially transposed matrix
    st1 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x1], #64
    st1 {v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d, v3.2d}, [x1], #64
    st1 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x1], #64
    st1 {v4.2d, v5.2d, v6.2d, v7.2d}, [x1], #64

    ret
ENDFUNC(xpose_half)

FUNC(xpose_final)
    ld1 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x2], #64
    ld1 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x3], #64
    ld1 {v20.2d, v21.2d, v22.2d, v23.2d}, [x2], #64
    ld1 {v28.2d, v29.2d, v30.2d, v31.2d}, [x3], #64

    trn1    v0.4s, v16.4s, v24.4s
    trn2    v4.4s, v16.4s, v24.4s
    trn1    v1.4s, v17.4s, v25.4s
    trn2    v5.4s, v17.4s, v25.4s
    trn1    v2.4s, v18.4s, v26.4s
    trn2    v6.4s, v18.4s, v26.4s
    trn1    v3.4s, v19.4s, v27.4s
    trn2    v7.4s, v19.4s, v27.4s

    trn1    v16.4s, v20.4s, v28.4s
    trn2    v24.4s, v20.4s, v28.4s
    trn1    v17.4s, v21.4s, v29.4s
    trn2    v25.4s, v21.4s, v29.4s
    trn1    v18.4s, v22.4s, v30.4s
    trn2    v26.4s, v22.4s, v30.4s
    trn1    v19.4s, v23.4s, v31.4s
    trn2    v27.4s, v23.4s, v31.4s

    st1 {v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d, v3.2d}, [x5], #64
    st1 {v4.2d, v5.2d, v6.2d, v7.2d}, [x6], #64
    st1 {v16.2d, v17.2d, v18.2d, v19.2d}, [x5], #64
    st1 {v24.2d, v25.2d, v26.2d, v27.2d}, [x6], #64

    ret
ENDFUNC(xpose_final)
```

Comment: I'm happy that you found a way to implement the recursive transposition algorithm I outlined in a probably more efficient manner.  I'll go ahead and add it to the benchmark set above later.

Comment: @fuz fyi, I came up with "recursive transposition" by myself already when I was a teenager. Your answer was just a self explanatory noob stuff for me and was pointting out that it lacks the essential memory operation. And you exceeded my expectation: your full code is a plain joke. Seriously, why do you write assembly codes in first place?

Comment: If you were aware of it before, even better.  I'm happy that I helped you recall it.  Though some comments might make it easier for others to understand what is going on.  After all, Stack Overflow is a site for understanding, not for copying other people's code.

Answer (score -2):

The data size far exceeds the size of the register bank. You have a choice between:

- strided load and consecutive store
- consecutive load and strided store

And consecutive store is always much more preferrable.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>    
void transposeBitwise64x64(uint64_t *pDst, uint64_t *pSrc)
    {
        uint8x8_t drow0, drow1, drow2, drow3, drow4, drow5, drow6, drow7;
        uint8x8_t dtmp0, dtmp1, dtmp2, dtmp3, dtmp4, dtmp5, dtmp6, dtmp7;
        uint8x16_t qrow0, qrow1, qrow2, qrow3, qrow4, qrow5, qrow6, qrow7;
        uint8x16_t qtmp0, qtmp1, qtmp2, qtmp3, qtmp4, qtmp5, qtmp6, qtmp7;
        const intptr_t sstride = 16;
        uint8_t *pSrc1, *pSrc2, *pSrcBase;
        uint32_t count = 8;
    
        drow0 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow1 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow2 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow3 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow4 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow5 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow6 = vmov_n_u8(0);
        drow7 = vmov_n_u8(0);
    
        pSrcBase = (uint8_t *) pSrc;
    
        do {
            pSrc1 = pSrcBase;
            pSrc2 = pSrcBase + 8;
            pSrcBase += 1;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 0); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 0); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 0); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 0); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 0); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 0); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 0); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 0); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 1); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 1); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 1); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 1); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 1); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 1); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 1); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 1); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 2); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 2); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 2); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 2); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 2); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 2); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 2); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 2); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 3); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 3); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 3); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 3); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 3); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 3); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 3); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 3); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 4); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 4); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 4); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 4); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 4); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 4); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 4); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 4); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 5); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 5); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 5); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 5); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 5); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 5); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 5); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 5); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 6); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 6); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 6); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 6); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 6); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 6); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 6); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 6); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow0 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow0, 7); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow1 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow1, 7); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow2 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow2, 7); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow3 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow3, 7); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow4 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow4, 7); pSrc1 += sstride;
            drow5 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow5, 7); pSrc2 += sstride;
            drow6 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc1, drow6, 7);
            drow7 = vld1_lane_u8(pSrc2, drow7, 7);
    
            dtmp0 = vshr_n_u8(drow0, 1);
            dtmp1 = vshr_n_u8(drow1, 1);
            dtmp2 = vshr_n_u8(drow2, 1);
            dtmp3 = vshr_n_u8(drow3, 1);
            dtmp4 = vshr_n_u8(drow4, 1);
            dtmp5 = vshr_n_u8(drow5, 1);
            dtmp6 = vshr_n_u8(drow6, 1);
            dtmp7 = vshr_n_u8(drow7, 1);
    
            qrow0 = vcombine_u8(drow0, dtmp0);
            qrow1 = vcombine_u8(drow1, dtmp1);
            qrow2 = vcombine_u8(drow2, dtmp2);
            qrow3 = vcombine_u8(drow3, dtmp3);
            qrow4 = vcombine_u8(drow4, dtmp4);
            qrow5 = vcombine_u8(drow5, dtmp5);
            qrow6 = vcombine_u8(drow6, dtmp6);
            qrow7 = vcombine_u8(drow7, dtmp7);
    
    //////////////////////////////////////
    
            qtmp0 = qrow0;
            qtmp1 = qrow1;
            qtmp2 = qrow2;
            qtmp3 = qrow3;
            qtmp4 = qrow4;
            qtmp5 = qrow5;
            qtmp6 = qrow6;
            qtmp7 = qrow7;
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp1, 1);
            qtmp2 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp2, qtmp3, 1);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp5, 1);
            qtmp6 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp6, qtmp7, 1);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp2, 2);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp6, 2);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp4, 4);
    
            vst1q_u8((uint8_t *)pDst, qtmp0); pDst += 2;
    
    //////////////////////////////////////
    
            qtmp0 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow0, 2);
            qtmp1 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow1, 2);
            qtmp2 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow2, 2);
            qtmp3 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow3, 2);
            qtmp4 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow4, 2);
            qtmp5 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow5, 2);
            qtmp6 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow6, 2);
            qtmp7 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow7, 2);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp1, 1);
            qtmp2 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp2, qtmp3, 1);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp5, 1);
            qtmp6 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp6, qtmp7, 1);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp2, 2);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp6, 2);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp4, 4);
    
            vst1q_u8((uint8_t *)pDst, qtmp0); pDst += 2;
    
            //////////////////////////////////////
    
            qtmp0 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow0, 4);
            qtmp1 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow1, 4);
            qtmp2 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow2, 4);
            qtmp3 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow3, 4);
            qtmp4 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow4, 4);
            qtmp5 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow5, 4);
            qtmp6 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow6, 4);
            qtmp7 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow7, 4);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp1, 1);
            qtmp2 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp2, qtmp3, 1);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp5, 1);
            qtmp6 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp6, qtmp7, 1);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp2, 2);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp6, 2);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp4, 4);
    
            vst1q_u8((uint8_t *)pDst, qtmp0); pDst += 2;
    
            //////////////////////////////////////
    
            qtmp0 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow0, 6);
            qtmp1 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow1, 6);
            qtmp2 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow2, 6);
            qtmp3 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow3, 6);
            qtmp4 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow4, 6);
            qtmp5 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow5, 6);
            qtmp6 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow6, 6);
            qtmp7 = vshrq_n_u8(qrow7, 6);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp1, 1);
            qtmp2 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp2, qtmp3, 1);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp5, 1);
            qtmp6 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp6, qtmp7, 1);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp2, 2);
            qtmp4 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp4, qtmp6, 2);
    
            qtmp0 = vsliq_n_u8(qtmp0, qtmp4, 4);
    
            vst1q_u8((uint8_t *)pDst, qtmp0); pDst += 2;
    
        } while (--count);
    }
```

I tried my best to talk the compiler into generating optimized machine codes, but they simply won't listen: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oj1x1f3EE)
Especially GCC sucks (as always).
I'll add an assembly version by tomorrow.

Comment: That does not look very efficient.  The recursive transposition algorithm is a lot faster.

Comment: @fuz Show me what's "efficient" then. I'm waiting. Are you sure you understood OP's problem correctly? Are you aware that neon doesn't have unlimited registers?

Comment: I have outlined the basic efficient algorithm in my comment.  I mean there's no point about yours.  It's so inefficient, you didn't even try to use `vld4` to save 75% of the loads.

Comment: @fuz Now I see you didn't understand OP's problem. Good luck with strided stores then, stalling the write buffer.

Comment: Strided loads and stores aren't even required with an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @fuz provided NEON has something like 128 registers. You are dealing here with 64x8= 512 bytes. Good luck~

Comment: Yes, clearly you have to store and reload a few times to get this done, but none of the stores and reloads are strided.

Comment: Yes, which is why you need 512 loads in total.  That's quite a lot.

Comment: Just show me your code. Let's count then. 512 loads are much better than 512 stores.

Comment: Curiously enough, my implementation managed to make do with just 24 SIMD registers.  This saved me from having to spill callee saved NEON registers onto the stack.  As for `sli` and `sri`, these indeed helped, but only in the step where a `0x0f` mask would be used otherwise.

Comment: @fuz Ah, great. I explicitly said the OP needs to write `aarch32` and `aarch64` separately. I first worte it in intrinsics for `aarch32`'s 16 q-registers and expressed my displeasure with compilers, and you run benchmark with it on your terms. Your supervising professor should teach you some code of conduct above anyhing else. BTW, I had to abandon the office in hurry due to a Corona infectee. Just wait a few days until things get resolved.

Comment: @fuz You wrote the `aarch32` version in assembly, right? Why don't you try it in intrinsics, and be amazed by the mess the compiler generates? You should be **VERY** careful with intrinsics, especially for `aarch32`. And you didn't get it. I'm currently under quarantine for ten days. Please don't worry, it seems I'm not infected.

Comment: @fuz: Jake has written quite a few good NEON / SIMD SO answers in pure assembly.  I think he generally knows what he's doing most of the time.  (Maybe he's grumpy from being in quarantine?  His initial unjustified rudeness on your answer seems to have really spiralled out of control in comments here into rudeness on both sides).  Perhaps his point about macros is for instruction-scheduling reasons, which is fair if you want to further micro-optimize your strategy to be even more than 3x faster on in-order CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm sorry for you getting dragged into this.  I should have stopped earlier.  The point of my macro usage was that I wanted to make the code easy to understand so a wide audience can benefit from it.  Of course the instruction schedule and other details have to be adapted to the specific microarchitecture the code will be used for.